# Selecting multipe character values in a column to replace them with the same value

Tags: r

I think I should be able to do this in one line but I am pretty new and don't know how. I would like to keep the solution as simple as possible.

```
COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup[COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup == "0-9"] <- "<50"
COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup[COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup == "10-19"] <- "<50"
COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup[COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup == "20-29"] <- "<50"
COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup[COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup == "30-39"] <- "<50"
COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup[COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup == "40-49"] <- "<50"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```r
COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup[COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup %in% c("0-9", "10-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49")] <- "<50"
```

which simplifies your code to one line.

If there are - for example - just two more groups like `"50-59"` and `"60+"` you could use (notice the `!`):

```r
COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup[!COVID_19_cases_2021_ageknown$Agegroup %in% c("50-59", "60+")] <- "<50"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!